# marionnet: tc command and RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported

Tags: linux, networking

using marionnet to practice networking I'm having problem using the command tc:traffic control. I get the RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported.
Anyway I can jump over this hurdle?

Comment: Marionnet is using User Mode Linux to provide virtualization: it's a Linux kernel configured as a standard process. What kernel is it and where does it come from? Was [`NET_SCHED`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NET_SCHED.html) support compiled in this kernel? For example Debian's [user-mode-linux package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/user-mode-linux) does have `NET_SCHED` compiled in (as can be seen with the `.../sched/` directory in the [list of files](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/user-mode-linux/filelist)).  Or is it your own kernel that is lacking this feature?

Comment: the kernel type in /usr/local/share/marionnet/kernels is linux-3.2.64-ghost. I got it by just using the script marionnet_from_scratch.sh that I got from the marionnet website and it did everything on it own. 
How do I know if NET_SCHED was compiled into  the kernel. I don't think there is a problem with the host machine kernel because running tc on it works. It doesnt work in marionnet though..

Comment: https://www.marionnet.org/download/marionnet_from_scratch/0.94.x/kernels_linux-3.2.64-ghost.tar.gz doesn't have CONFIG_NET_SCHED in its linux-3.2.64-ghost.config . That's the cause

Comment: If you were using Debian 9, i'd tell to use the packaged version of marionnet which would offer to use the user-mode-linux package with the needed option and you'd be done. Here you can perhaps manage to reuse it on the wheezy (Debian 7) image from upstream, or you can compile the kernel yourself, but I wouldn't know how to explain either in an answer